# Запись результата в файл СИ (ошибка)

Tags: c, файловый-ввод-вывод

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите разобраться в условии. Я вроде сделал, но не уверен.
Помогите результат записать в файл.

```
int main()
{
    int x,y;    
    FILE *f = fopen("y.txt", "r"); 

    printf ("Vvedite perenemyu X = ");
    scanf ("%d", &x);

        if (x >= 10) y = 1;
            else if (x > -0.5 && x < 10 && x != 0) y = 0;
                else if (x < -0.5) y = -1;



    fprintf(f,"y = %d\n",y);
    fclose (f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Проверить проще, чем спрашивать. И я вообще не уверен что ваш код себерется...

Comment: аааа мммм, ты хоть понял, что ты написал ?

Comment: Во первых поняЛИ. А во вторых - поняли ли вы?

Comment: Что же нам делать, если `х` все-таки будет равен нулю или 0.5?

Answer (score 1):

```
int y;
if (x >= 10) y = 1;
else if (x > -0.5 && x < 10 && x != 0) y = 0;
else if (x < -0.5) y = -1;
```

Проблема в том, что при `x==0` и `x == -0.5` значение `y` просто неизвестно.

У вас вот это выражение `-0.5<x<10` будет трактоваться как `(-0.5 < x) < 10`? т.е. результат сравнения в скобках (`true`  или `false`) будет сравниваться с 10, и всегда даст `true`.

Надеюсь, что считать значение `double x` с помощью `scanf("%lf")` вы сумеете?

Да, условие `x < 10` можно выбросить - раз уж до него добрались, `x` точно меньше 10... А вот про `x < 0.5` этого нельзя сказать - то же значение 0 пройдет до последнего `if`...

Comment: я вот ввожу Х, оно все это считает и проверяет, а выводить нужно Y ?

Comment: Ну само собой...

Comment: это надо так писать printf ("y= ", &y) ?

Comment: Вы вообще-то на лекциях хоть иногда бывали? :) `printf("y = %d\n",y);` - если, конечно, `y` объявлена как `int`...

Comment: это было очень давно, ОЧЕНЬ ))

Comment: если еще маленький вопросик, как результат записать в файл )?

Comment: Открыть файл с помощью `fopen`, использовать `fprintf`, закрыть файл с помощью `fclose`...